# Salesforce not letting select country from a relationship, but allows name and id

Tags: soql

I am running the following query in salesforce to get the country

```
SELECt name, owner.country from lead
```

This gives the following error:

```
No such column 'country' on entity 'Name'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

However this works just fine if I do

```
SELECt name, owner.id from lead
SELECt name, owner.username from lead
SELECt name, owner.name from lead
```

It gives the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a result of the OwnerId field on Lead being a 'Polymorphic' relationship field i.e. it relates to more than one object (User or Group).

This field actually looks up to a 'Name' object. You can use the Force.com IDE schema browser to see what fields are available on this object:

[image: schema browser]

As you can see, there is no 'Country' field hence the error you're getting.

There's a great article on the subject [here](http://www.tgerm.com/2010/11/no-such-column-on-entity-error.html)

backed up by SFDC documentation [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm#relates_and_polymorph_keys)

and [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_polymorphic_relationships.htm)